# Laravel - where() по sum() поля в связанной модели

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть модель `Invoice` (счёт) с полем `cost` (цена). Если модель `Payment`, связанная с моделью `Invoice` полем `invoice_id`. Связь один ко многим - у счёта может быть сколько угодно платежей (оплата в несколько этапов, например). У модели `Payment` есть поле `amount` (сумма платежа). Мне нужно сделать следующее (псевдокод):

Invoice::where(sum(Payment.amount) == Invoice.cost)

То есть, выбрать все счета, у которых сумма их платежей совпадёт со стоимостью в счёте (оплаченные, короче, счета). Запрашивать данные и фильтровать через `foreach()` или через методы `Collection` не вариант - как минимум, сломается пагинация, построенная на `take()` и `skip()`, да и вообще кривой это подход. Нужно средствами БД. Пробовал через `whereHas`, запутался, ниасилил.

P.S. База PostgreSQL

Comment: Работа с результатом агрегирования значений записей группы (SUM) выполняется с использованием HAVING, а не WHERE.

Comment: @Akina ну это ништяк. Это я в соседнем вопросе уже видел. Мне бы конкретнее немного, с примерами.

Comment: Будет что-то типа `Invoice::having(db::raw("sum(Payment.amount)") == Invoice.cost)`

Comment: @Akina а, ну через `db::raw` короче лучше, ну окей. Я просто думал вдруг без raw есть способ, который мне неизвестен. Благодарю